# Building Dynamic HTML Email Content with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-email

I have a python dictionary that I'd like to send an email with in the form of a two column table, where I have a Title and the two column headers, and the key,value pair of the dictionary populated into the rows.

```
<tr>
<th colspan="2">
<h3><br>title</h3>
</th> </tr>
<th> Column 1 </th>
<th> Column 2 </th>
"Thn dynamic amount of <tr><td>%column1data%</td><td>%column2data%</td></tr>
```

The column1 and column2 data are the key,value pairs from the associated dictionary.

Is there a way to do this in a simple manner? This is an auotmated email being sent out via a cronjob, once a day after populating the data.

Thank you all.
P.S I know nothing about markdown :/

P.S.S I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Would the email you're sending have any other 'static' data in it? In other words would you benefit from a templating tool like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)?

Comment: Right now the email is fairly simple, however, in the future it may contain some data analytics components like graphs, so Im open to any light frameworks that could provide those capabilities. But something simple now would at least get it going.

Comment: Jinja is the way to go here.

Comment: Would I be able to get a rough example of what I want to do?  I'm rather new to python in general

Comment: @gandolf Done; see my response below for a full working example that you can modify to suit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Basic Example:** (*with templating*)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from smtplib import SMTP              # sending email
from email.mime.text import MIMEText  # constructing messages

from jinja2 import Environment        # Jinja2 templating

TEMPLATE = """
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

Hello World!.

</body>
</html>
"""  # Our HTML Template

# Create a text/html message from a rendered template
msg = MIMEText(
    Environment().from_string(TEMPLATE).render(
        title='Hello World!'
    ), "html"
)

subject = "Subject Line"
sender= "root@localhost"
recipient = "root@localhost"

msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipient

# Send the message via our own local SMTP server.
s = SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(sender, [recipient], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

*Relevant Documentation:*

- [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)
- [email.mime.text](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html)
- [smeplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)

**NB:** This *assumes* you have a valid [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) on your local system.

**Note Also:** That you may in fact actually want to use a multipart message when composing the email; See [Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#email-examples)

**Update:** As an aside there are some really nice(er) "email sending" libraries out there that may be of interest to you:

- [sender](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sender)
- [outbox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/outbox)
- [Envelopes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Envelopes/0.4)

*I believe these libraries are along the same lines as [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) -- SMTP for Humans*

Comment: Hi James, thanks for this example. In my particular case where I want to add dynamic content, where would something like "for key,value in dic.items(): " appear to add the rows in the template?

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks James I will mark this as the answer since it did get me to the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @gandolf No problems! Glad it helped you on your way :)

Comment: Just for others, *smeplib* under the Relevant Documentation should be *smtplib*. Great soln

Answer (score 2):

Another tool that you can leverage (and which my company is using in production itself) is Mandrill. It's a service by Mailchimp, but instead of mass email newsletters, it provides "transactional" emails, i.e. individual, personalized emails. It's free for the first 10,000 emails you send per month, and frees you from the burden of administering a private email server, as well as providing some very nice WYSIWYG editing tools, automatic open rate & click rate tracking, and clean, simple python APIs.

The workflow that my company is using is:

1. Create a template using the WYSIWYG editor in Mailchimp. The dynamic data can be inserted into the template at runtime later as "merge vars".
2. Import that template from Mailchimp into Mandrill
3. Use a cronjob python script to retrieve the dynamic data and send it to the Mandrill server to be sent out.

Sample python code using the official Mandrill Python library:

```
import mandrill
mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(mandrill_api_key)
message = {
    'from_email': 'gandolf@email.com',
    'from_name': 'Gandolf',
    'subject': 'Hello World',
    'to': [
        {
            'email': 'recipient@email.com',
            'name': 'recipient_name',
            'type': 'to'
        }
    ],
    "merge_vars": [
        {
            "rcpt": "recipient.email@example.com",
            "vars": [
                {
                    "name": "merge1",
                    "content": "merge1 content"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
result = mandrill_client.messages.send_template(template_name="Your Template", message=message)
```